# C++: How to guarantee include order of header files in a project when the order really matters

Tags: c++, glfw

The question is asked because in some situation the include order really matters. For example, as said on [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window) or the [GLFW doc](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html),  `glad.h` must be included before `glfw3.h`.

For including headers, I have been following the rule that each file should only include its necessary headers explicitly, and headers should all have include guards.

Thus the problem comes. In a project, some files only need `glfw3.h` and some only need `glad.h`. Then when compiling, how to guarantee the compiler always reads `glad.h` before `glfw3.h`?

Two solutions I can think of are:

1. manually arrange the order of source files when feeding them to the compiler.
2. write a new header file called `glad_glfw.h` which contains the two headers in the right order. Then any other files which need to include any of the two include the `glad_glfw.h`.

I think 1. would eventually be difficult when the project grows large, and 2. kind of violates the rule of minimum include. So I want to ask if there are any better ways to do this?

Comment: This must be enforced by the header files themselves. There are a number of ways to enforce this, but header files must be changed to do that. You can't enforce this outside of the header files, except as according to your 2nd solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You mean I have to change the library headers?

Comment: Yes. One header file `#define`s a preprocessor symbol. The second header file reports an `#error` if the symbol is `#ifdef`ed. This is the right way to do it. You can't do anything if the library header files do not enforce correct usage.

Comment: I don't see how 2 violates rule of minimum include.

Comment: If you own the header files, you can instrument them so that they `#error` if not included in the right order, by using header guards and checks.  If you do not own the header files (i.e., you can't modify them), you can make shim header files that include the real header files in the right order, and only use your shim header files in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `#pragma once` as an include guard.

A little less prone to programmer error than #ifdef's, but it is a little non-standard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option - "option 3," perhaps - would be to include those header files in a "[precompiled header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header)."  This is especially useful if you expect the header files themselves to rarely, if ever, change.